# HTML5 Canvas: fontBoundingBoxAscent vs. actualBoundingBoxAscent

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The [TextMetrics API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics) returns a few fields with similar names:

- `fontBoundingBoxAscent` vs. `actualBoundingBoxAscent`
- `fontBoundingBoxDescent` vs. `actualBoundingBoxDescent`

The MDN docs is not very clear and does not provide a visual. What is the difference between them?

Also, as a follow-up, how can I calculate the height of the text from these values?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps these documentation are more clear:

> **fontBoundingBoxAscent**
>
> The distance from the horizontal line indicated by the textBaseline
>   attribute to the top of the *highest* bounding rectangle of all the
>   fonts used to render the text, in CSS pixels; positive numbers
>   indicating a distance going up from the given baseline.'
>
> **fontBoundingBoxDescent**
>
> The distance from the horizontal line indicated by the textBaseline
>   attribute to the bottom of the *lowest* bounding rectangle of all the
>   fonts used to render the text, in CSS pixels; positive numbers
>   indicating a distance going down from the given baseline.
>
> **actualBoundingBoxAscent**
>
> The distance from the horizontal line indicated by the textBaseline
>   attribute to the top of the bounding rectangle of the given text, in
>   CSS pixels; positive numbers indicating a distance going *up* from the
>   given baseline.
>
> **actualBoundingBoxDescent**
>
> The distance from the horizontal line indicated by the textBaseline
>   attribute to the bottom of the bounding rectangle of the given text,
>   in CSS pixels; positive numbers indicating a distance going *down*
>   from the given baseline.
>
> **Source**:
>
> https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/canvas/TextMetrics/fontBoundingBoxAscent/
>   https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/canvas/TextMetrics/fontBoundingBoxDescent/
>   https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/canvas/TextMetrics/actualBoundingBoxAscent/
>   https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/canvas/TextMetrics/actualBoundingBoxDescent/

To calculate the text height you can do the following:

```
fontHeight = fontBoundingBoxAscent + fontBoundingBoxDescent;
actualHeight = actualBoundingBoxAscent + actualBoundingBoxDescent;
```

`fontHeight` is the bounding box height regardless of the string being rendered. `actualHeight` is specific to the string being rendered.